# Pyspark: Convert Dense vector to columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame with four columns, with one column being a dense vector.

| cust_id | label | prediction | probability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | {"vectorType":"dense","length":2,"values":[0.5745528913772013,0.4254471086227987]} |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | {"vectorType":"dense","length":2,"values":[0.5185219003114524,0.4814780996885476]} |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | {"vectorType":"dense","length":2,"values":[0.37871114732242217,0.6212888526775778]} |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | {"vectorType":"dense","length":2,"values":[0.4352110724347864,0.5647889275652135]} |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | {"vectorType":"dense","length":2,"values":[0.49476519185173606,0.505234808148264]} |

I want to convert the dense vector to columns and store the output along with the remaining columns.

| cust_id | label | prediction | split_int[0] | split_int[1] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.574552891 | 0.425447109 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0.5185219 | 0.4814781 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0.378711147 | 0.621288853 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0.435211072 | 0.564788928 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 0.494765192 | 0.505234808 |

I found some code online and was able to split the dense vector.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType

def split_array_to_list(col):
    def to_list(v):
        return v.toArray().tolist()
    return F.udf(to_list, ArrayType(DoubleType()))(col)

df3 = selected.select(split_array_to_list(F.col("probability")).alias("split_int")).select([F.col("split_int")[i] for i in range(2)])
df3.show()
```

How can I add other columns? I tried this but getting
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

```
df3 = selected.select(F.col("cust_id") + ((split_array_to_list(F.col("probability")).alias("split_int")).select([F.col("split_int")[i] for i in range(2)])))
```

Comment: what does `selected.printSchema()` print?

Comment: it gives cust_id: integer, label: integer, prediction: integer, probability: vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `withColumn` when using your udf

```
df3 = selected.withColumn("split_int", split_array_to_list(F.col("probability"))).select(F.col("*"), *[F.col("split_int")[i] for i in range(2)])
```